Getting linking error while testing to add vulkan shaderc in my project
CMakeLists.txt
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Vulkan::Vulkan)

int my shader.cpp
void OpenGLShader::Compile(const std::unordered_map<GLenum, std::string>& shaderSources)
    {       
        vk::Buffer;
        shaderc::Compiler compiler;
        shaderc::CompileOptions options;
    }

what iam try to do is testing if this works for shaderc but ima getting these error
out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compiler_release referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::Compiler::~Compiler(void)" (??1Compiler@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)
out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compile_options_initialize referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::CompileOptions::CompileOptions(void)" (??0CompileOptions@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)
\out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compile_options_initialize referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::CompileOptions::CompileOptions(void)" (??0CompileOptions@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)
\out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compile_options_release referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::CompileOptions::~CompileOptions(void)" (??1CompileOptions@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)


vk::Buffer;
this work fine but adding shaderc causes these errors can someone explain me what am i missing

Are you linking against shaderc?

I am just using link library Vulkan::Vulkan is there a link library for shaderc just like Vulkan::Vulkan ?

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE vulkan-1 shaderc_shared )

worked for me you need to manually add the vulkan using
if (DEFINED VULKAN_SDK_PATH)
  set(Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS "${VULKAN_SDK_PATH}/Include") # 1.1 Make sure this include path is correct
  set(Vulkan_LIBRARIES "${VULKAN_SDK_PATH}/Lib") # 1.2 Make sure lib path is correct
  set(Vulkan_FOUND "True")
else()
  find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED) # throws error if could not find Vulkan
  message(STATUS "Found Vulkan: $ENV{VULKAN_SDK}")
endif()

hope this help is some help to someone

The static library for shaderc is part of the optional components in FindVulkan as of CMake version 3.24, the import target is called Vulkan::shaderc_combined.
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Vulkan::Vulkan Vulkan::shaderc_combined)

FindVulkan will also define Vulkan_shaderc_combined_FOUND to specify whether it was actually able to find the shaderc static library, as well as its static library path in Vulkan_shaderc_combined_LIBRARY.
If you want to use the dynamic library, you'll need to use a more manual approach. You'll also need to include the shaderc_shared dynamic library in your distribution. There is also shaderc_sharedd if you want a debug build.
find_library(Vulkan_shaderc_LIBRARY NAMES shaderc PATHS ${VULKAN_SDK}/Lib)
find_library(Vulkan_shaderc_shared_LIBRARY NAMES shaderc_shared PATHS ${VULKAN_SDK}/Lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Vulkan::Vulkan ${Vulkan_shaderc_LIBRARY} ${Vulkan_shaderc_shared_LIBRARY})


getting this error when i includeVulkan::shaderc_combined 1> [CMake] CMake Error at ExternalLibrary/CMakeLists.txt:32 (target_link_libraries): 1> [CMake]   The link interface of target "Packages" contains: 1> [CMake]  1> [CMake]     Vulkan::shaderc_combined 1> [CMake]  1> [CMake]   but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include: 1> [CMake]  1> [CMake]     * There is a typo in the target name. 1> [CMake]     * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target. 1> [CMake]     * An ALIAS target is missing.

And when using Vulkan_shaderc_combined_LIBRARY to compile i get this \out\build\x64-debug\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Vulkan_shaderc_combined_LIBRARY.lib' what am i doing wrong

Using this i was able to compile target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE vulkan-1 shaderc_combined) but the strange thing is i am able to compile in release mode i am getting this in debug  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' also how i do add spriv cross if using these headers #include <spirv_cross/spirv_cross.hpp>
#include <spirv_cross/spirv_glsl.hpp>

You need to use at least CMake 3.24 for FindVulkan to find the optional packages. Your Vulkan installation also needs to have the libraries of course.

i am Using the latest cmake for my project i managed to make it work but only in release build in the debug it shows the same error  \out\build\x64-debug\shaderc_combined.lib(shaderc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in cmake_pch.cxx.obj
\out\build\x64-debug\shaderc_combined.lib(shaderc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in cmake_pch.cxx.obj  what am i doing wrong
